# Redirect aspx from MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created some menu on MVC. I want to redirect to aspx when user click on these menu.
Here's the menu:

```
<nav>
    <ul id="menu">
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Request", "Request", "Home")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Articles", "Articles", "Home")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Services", "Services", "Home")</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Where Home, About and Contact is in MVC i.e chtml but for Request, Articles and Services I have respective aspx page. Can some one tell me how can I redirect to aspx?

Comment: You can use both razor and aspx in the same project. Here is how :http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/asp-net-mvc-3-using-multiple-view-engines-in-same-project

Comment: I'm confused when you say `ASPX view engine`.  Webforms does not use ViewEngines.  Did you mean to say WebForms instead, or are you mixing WebForms and Razor view engines in the same MVC application?

Comment: @ErikPhilips That edit adding the words "view engine" may not be valid as it was not from the OP. user3540028, can you confirm whether this new interpretation is correct, or if you indeed meant Webforms (as my answer was directed at)?

Comment: @lc,@Erik Philips- What I meant to say is, I've included some webforms (.aspx) in MVC application. I have separated those webforms in a folder "Admin". Now I want to redirect those webforms (.aspx) from View (.cshtml). Actually I am new to MVC, in learning phase. So, dont know how or if can I do that.

Comment: That's what I thought. Unfortunately @CarrieKendall 's edit was not correct then and caused a bit of confusion. Please look at my answer below though, I think it's what you're looking for (I've edited it to show the "Admin" folder)

Comment: sorry about that, I should have reviewed more carefully

Comment: @CarrieKendall In all fairness the question truly could have been interpreted either way. I think I read into the question a bit and got lucky with my version :)

Answer (score 1):

One might argue the MVC way would be to create a controller which then does a redirect to the .aspx resource. However, you can use `UrlHelper.Content` with a relative path to get a URI for the resource. For example:

```
<a href="@Url.Content(~/Admin/request.aspx)">Request</a>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I tried another approach. Created an ActionResult for Request in the controller. And then RedirectResult ("URL").
    return new RedirectResult(url+"/Request.aspx");
 It also worked for me. But thanks a lot for your quick response on it.

Comment: @user3540028 Yes that was what I was referring to by "create a controller that then does a redirect to the .aspx resource". :)

Comment: I got it. Actually I couldn't understand that but after some more research I found and implemented the same. But now I got it. Thanks a ton.